# How to access a Python package's docstring?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a package `omegaproject` I'm importing from a script `test.py`:

```
test.py
omegaproject/
  __init__.py
  omega.py
```

Say that in `__init__.py` I've put `"""Hello there"""` and nothing else.

Now, say that `test.py` consists of:

```
import omegaproject 

print(omegaproject.__doc__)
```

Shouldn't running `test.py` cause Python to display 'Hello there'?  Instead, it displays nothing.

In other words, where do I specify the docstring of a package?

Comment: That's exactly how it works, but you are apparently not importing the correct package. Validate that you are indeed importing what you think you are by printing `omegaproject.__file__`.

Comment: if you `import omegaproject` and use `omegaproject.__doc__` from an ipython or a python shell, what happens?

Comment: You're right Martijn, it does work.  I had drawn up my example to simplify from my actual situation but did not actually test it before posting this question.

Now as I try to figure out how my actual situation differs from the simplified example, I'm having a hard time replicating the issue.  So never mind.

Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call this a "trick question" :)

As Martijn points out, in fact the docstring does appear as desired.

The problem was in this sequence of events:

1. I originally had `__init__.py` empty.
2. Then I ran `test.py`, which printed nothing.
3. Then I edited `__init__.py` to have a docstring reading `"""Hello there"""`
4. Then **on the interactive shell** I ran: `import omegaproject` followed by `omegaproject.__doc__`

But **omegaproject had already been imported**!  So the second import did nothing, the docstring did not get updated, and so the docstring was still showing as blank.